# Cross Correlation between highly unevenly spaced time series

Tags: time-series, survey, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have the following problem.

I have 2 time series, one on a yearly basis (2010 - 2020) and one on a daily basis (01/01/2010 - 31/12/2020).

I looking for methods how I can investigate the correlation between those 2 series since they are highly unevenly spaced.

Does anyone has suggestions or is this even possible in some way?

Comment: What form of correlation do you need?  For what purpose?  What kinds of quantities are you observing?  (For instance, would it make sense to sum a year's worth of daily values to obtain a single value for that year, or are your data more complex than that?)

Comment: The yearly based series is survey data and the daily based sentiment data. I want to check if the sentiment data is indeed linked with the survey data.

Comment: Okay.  Let's clear up one more thing: where you write "highly unevenly spaced," do you intend that to mean the distinction between the yearly spacing and daily spacing, or do you mean that one (or both) of the series does not involve an evenly spaced set of times?

Comment: The series on their own are equally spaced, I indeed mean the the distinction between the yearly spacing and daily spacing.